# C++, parse binary registry file (regf)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I have a question. There is a WinApi function RegSaveKey, which saves a registry key into a binary file. I know that this file can be loaded by RegLoadKey.

But, how can I parse this binary file without that function? Actually, I'm looking not for a complete code, but for description of format of that files.

Again, no need to parse TEXT *.reg files, I want to parse BINARY files like NTUSER.DAT and others at %system32%\config\ directory.

UPD: no need to write to registry in that way, only read

Answer (score 1):

I think [this libregf project here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libregf/) can help. I haven't looked into it but assumed they implemented it without pushing the file back to registry and then reading from there or something like that.

Comment: it seems to be what I was looking for. Now need to understand how it works

Comment: @Tolga: Please annotate links - since your answer contains only link. Everyone must follow through the link to understand this answer and if ever the link is broken - it will render your answer useless. Hence urge you to edit your answer.